# How to change an ID's NA to character value, based on other ID's cell values/characteristics in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na

I have a problem in my dataset with missing values. For some reason, several ID’s miss a value at the column ‘Names’. This is strange, because other ID’s (with the same CODE (there are more codes in my whole dataset (>10K) and same year(6 options for years)) do have a value in that column.

Can somebody help me figuring out the code, so that ID’s with missing values in the ‘Names’ column, do get the same character value in ‘Names’ column, if other ID’s with the same code and year, do have a value in that column?

For example: the NA at row 4; should change to 'Hospital'; based on the same code and year, of another ID.(In my original dataframe there is an ID with 2013 and code 01 with name 'Hospital'; if not, it should stay NA).

Sidenote: it is panel data, so each ID can be in the dataset for multiple years (and rows; each year is one row) and not everybody is in for every year. There are also more variables in my dataframe.

```
> dput(Dataframe[1:7, ])
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), format.spss = "F9.3"), CODE = c("01", "01", "01","01", "01", "01", "01"), Year = structure(c(2018, 2014, 2018, 2013, 2013, 2015, 2015), format.spss = "F9.3"), Quarter = structure(c(3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3), format.spss = "F9.3"), Size = c(24.5, 23.25, 24.5, 30, 30, 19.25, 19.25), Names = c("Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", NA, "Hospital", NA, "Hospital")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"

A tibble: 7 x 8
  ID Gender CODE Year Quarter Size Names
       <dbl>      <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>                  
1  1          2 01          2018               3            24.5 Hospital
2  2          1 01          2014               4            23.2 Hospital
3  2          1 01          2018               4            24.5 Hospital
4  2          1 01          2013               4            30   NA                     
5  2          1 01          2013               3            30   Hospital
6  2          1 01          2015               4            19.2 NA                     
7  2          1 01          2015               3            19.2 Hospital
```

Selecting and checking indvidual rows is too much work, I have over 1.1 million rows..

Edit: it also possible to transfer the 'names' column to 1 if it has a (character) value, and 0 if NA.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure because in your example all the names are the same but I think this might do what you are looking for.

I changed the example below to have the last Names be "Not Hospital".

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), format.spss = "F9.3"), CODE = c("01", "01", "01","01", "01", "01", "01"), Year = structure(c(2018, 2014, 2018, 2013, 2013, 2015, 2015), format.spss = "F9.3"), Quarter = structure(c(3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3), format.spss = "F9.3"), Size = c(24.5, 23.25, 24.5, 30, 30, 19.25, 19.25), Names = c("Hospital", "Hospital", "Hospital", NA, "Hospital", NA, "Not Hospital")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame") )
```

Original

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
     ID CODE   Year Quarter  Size Names       
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
1     1 01     2018       3  24.5 Hospital    
2     2 01     2014       4  23.2 Hospital    
3     2 01     2018       4  24.5 Hospital    
4     2 01     2013       4  30   NA          
5     2 01     2013       3  30   Hospital    
6     2 01     2015       4  19.2 NA          
7     2 01     2015       3  19.2 Not Hospital
```

Here's the code to update the names.

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Names)) %>%
  select(CODE, Year, Names)  %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  summarise() %>%
  right_join(df, by = c("CODE", "Year")) %>%
  rename(Names = Names.x) %>%
  select(-Names.y)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   CODE, Year [4]
  CODE   Year Names           ID Quarter  Size
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 01     2018 Hospital         1       3  24.5
2 01     2014 Hospital         2       4  23.2
3 01     2018 Hospital         2       4  24.5
4 01     2013 Hospital         2       4  30  
5 01     2013 Hospital         2       3  30  
6 01     2015 Not Hospital     2       4  19.2
7 01     2015 Not Hospital     2       3  19.2
```

Comment: Hi dpmcsuss, in my exmaple dataframe it worked! Im going to check if it is working on my big dataset now, with different name and codes. Thank you for you effort!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach this problem, as far as I can see. However, I prefer the following solution.

The first step is to split the data frame into two. One data frame contains only rows without NA's in the Names column, while the other contains only rows with NA's in the Names column. Then, you simply search in the former for CODE YEAR combinations and return the name of the corresponding row. The first is to collect the rows that contain NA's, and take this to search for code and year combinations.

```
# Your data frame
df <- 

# Split df
df.with.nas <- df[ is.na(df$Names) ,]
df.without.nas <- df[ !is.na(df$Names) ,]

# Define function to separat logic
get.name <- function(row) {
  # row is an atomic vector. Hence we have to use row["<SELECTOR>"]
  result <- subset(df.without.nas, CODE == row["CODE"] & Year == row["Year"])
  return(result["Names"])
}

# Finally, search and return.
row.axis <- 1
df.with.nas$Names <- apply(df.with.nas, row.axis, get.name)

# Combine the dfs
df <- rbind(
  df.with.nas, df.without.nas)
```

This solution has a shortcoming. What should happen, when we find dublicates?

I hope this useful!